# Resetting page formats?

Tags: latex

I am currently using latex, with the book document class, for a big CS project. It's about 150 pages right now, but I noticed something very odd.

Randomly about half way through the document, the page formatting breaks.  When I do a

```
\chapter{newchapter}
```

about half way through this, it creates about a page of space between it and all of the sections.  E.g.:

GOOD:

```
PAGEHEADER

CHAPTER

SECTION #1
 Text goes here
```

This works fine up until about half way through the document, when this starts to happen on all following chapters/sections:

BAD:

```
PAGEHEADER





CHAPTER 2





SECTION #1






Text goes here.
```

I do not know why this happens, but no amount of `\newpage`, page breaking, will fix this. The section directly before it has a lot of embedded PNGs, but I don't see why that would cause a formatting issue.

When playing with some of the random `\setlength` commands, I managed to make a bit of a difference but not really.

Is there a way to force a document to reset its formatting?

*EDIT*

So I figured it out, I did a `\newpage` after the `Section1` text and fixed the issues, seems that latex was trying to group both the first section and the following section with the image. I don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suspect would be the png's. To confirm, comment out the image inclusion lines and check the formatting. Images have always been the weak point of using latex.